# Aggregate data frame column into lists based on empty column

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate a specific column of a data frame into lists and concatenate the rows.  Thank for the help.  Example:

```
df <-data.frame(id=c(12,NA,NA,15,NA),name=c("John",NA,NA,"Jane",NA),grades=c(88,65,94,73,77))
> df
  id name grades
1 12 John     88
2 NA <NA>     65
3 NA <NA>     94
4 15 Jane     73
5 NA <NA>     77
```

I need to resulting data frame to look like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(12,15),name=c("John","Jane"))
df1$grades <- list(c(88,65,94),c(73,77))
> df1
  id name     grades
1 12 John 88, 65, 94
2 15 Jane     73, 77
```

Comment: Look at the `no.locf` function from "zoo" to start....

Answer (score 3):

Fill in the `NA` values using `na.locf` from the "zoo" package, then use your preferred method of aggregation. For example, here's an approach using the `aggregate` function in base R:

```
library(zoo)
aggregate(grades ~ id + name, na.locf(df), c)
#   id name     grades
# 1 15 Jane     73, 77
# 2 12 John 88, 65, 94
str(.Last.value)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ id    : chr  "15" "12"
#  $ name  : chr  "Jane" "John"
#  $ grades:List of 2
#   ..$ 1.2: chr  "73" "77"
#   ..$ 2.1: chr  "88" "65" "94"
```

Comment: looks great! My actual data frame has ~100 columns.  Any idea how to avoid writing "grades~ id + name + ...x100.. +" for the aggregation part?

Comment: @Eric, try: `aggregate(grades ~ ., na.locf(df), c)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `data.table` and `zoo` packages (assuming `grades` is the third column):

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(zoo::na.locf(df))[,.(grades= list(grades)), by=names(df[,-3])]

#    id name     grades 
# 1: 12 John 88, 65, 94 
# 2: 15 Jane     73, 77
```